# I am getting error in angular while uploading image file

Tags: angular

media.components.html

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="position:relative;top:105px;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- form company info -->
        <div class="card card-outline-secondary">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="mb-0" style="text-align:center;">Company Information </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form autocomplete="off" class="form" role="form" name="form" [formGroup]="companyInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="companyInfoRequest()">


            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Company Logo:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input #fileInput style="display:none;" class="form-control" type="file" (change)="onFileChangedForImage($event)"
                    accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp">
                <button *ngIf="selectFilebutton" type="button" style="width:100%;padding:2px;" (click)="fileInput.click()">Select FIle</button>
                <span *ngIf="imageFileCheck" style="text-align:center">{{imageFileName}}</span>
                <!-- <input class="form-control" type="file" (change)="onFileChangedForImage($event)" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp"> -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">
                <span class="redtxt">*</span> Company Name:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="companyinfomodel.company_name" type="text" name="name"
                    formControlName="companyName" />
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.companyName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.companyName.errors.required">Please enter a Company Name</div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                <button class="btn btn-info">Next</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        </div><!-- /form user info -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

media.model.ts

```
    export class CompanyInformationModel {
        company_logo: File;
        company_name: string;
    }
```

media.components.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { CompanyInformationModel } from './media.model';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-media',
    templateUrl: './media.component.html'
    })
    export class MediaComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { 
        this.companyInfoForm = new FormGroup({
        company_name: new FormControl()
        });
    }
    companyinfomodel: CompanyInformationModel = {
        company_logo: null,
        company_name: ''

    }
    companyInfoForm: FormGroup;
    submitted = false;

    ngOnInit() {

    }

        // For company Logo
        selectFilebutton:boolean = true;
        imageFileCheck:boolean = false;
        imageFileName:string;
        onFileChangedForImage(event) {
        this.companyinfomodel.company_logo = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
        this.imageFileName = event.target.files[0].name;
        this.selectFilebutton = false;
        this.imageFileCheck = true;
        }

    // get f() { return this.companyInfoForm.controls; }
    companyInfoRequest() {
        this.submitted = true;
        const uploadData = new FormData();
        uploadData.append('company_logo', this.companyinfomodel.company_logo);
        uploadData.append('company_name', this.companyinfomodel.company_name);
        let id = 1;
        uploadData.append('company', '1');
        let body = uploadData;
        this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000', body)
        .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        })

    }
    }
```

Errors in console:

```
    Error: Cannot find control with name: 'companyName'
        at _throwError (forms.js:2144)
        at setUpControl (forms.js:2052)
        at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5281)
        at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5882)
        at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5803)
        at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21997)
        at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23265)
        at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23227)
        at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23861)
        at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23821)
```

Here i am trying to get media form data in angular.
I am have imported the same component in my app.module also.

It is showing global error as above in console.

I am expecting the data to come to my console only.

Then i will do my server operations.

Please have a look.

**Note**: It working when i am removing **company_name** field and keeping only **company_logo** file.

Comment: change `[formGroup]="myGroup"` to `[formGroup]="companyInfoForm"`

Comment: it already written the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **Form Collection Group** with you **formgroup** and make your **formControlName** as a part of it

**try this**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.companyInfoForm = formCollection.group({
        companyName: ["", Validators.required]
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised the formGroup.

You need to initialise it in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  this.companyInfoForm = new FormGroup();
}
```

But, after looking into your code, I think you are doing it wrong. You are doing a template-driven form but having some reactive-form component as well.
A template-driven form don't require formGroup at all. So you don't have to put `[formGroup]` inside the `<form>` tag.

But if your intention is to do reactive-form, you should not have `[(ngModel)]` in your HTML.

Your `companyInfoForm` need to be initialised in the constructor using the same data you have in `companyinfomodel`.

Take a look at [form builder](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder)

Comment: ERROR in src/app/media/media.component.ts(14,28): error TS2554: Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 0.

Comment: I can't help you with that error. I don't have any idea which line is that referring to.

Comment: I have simplified this code by keeping only file field. Please have  a look